# Why is DebuggerStepThrough ignored on linq statements?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq, debugging, breakpoints

While stepping through my code, I am finding certain lines deep down that are ignoring the DebuggerStepThrough attribute. It appears to be for within linq statements.

Here is a similar SO: [DebuggerStepThrough being ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559034/debuggerstepthrough-being-ignored)

*The code being stepped through is in Debug mode. It is in the same solution as the ReflectionHelper method below. The project reference is via project and not a compile dll elsewhere, I.e., the same output bin/debug folder as the project. Nothing else unusual is happening that may suggest the assembly being used is a different one as would be noticed while doing code changes on both project sides.*

So as I am stepping through using the <kbd>F11</kbd>, it steps into the code below.

I have the following in my `public static class ReflectionHelper`

```
[DebuggerStepThrough]
public static bool Exists(string propertyName, object srcObject)
{
    PropertyInfo propInfoSrcObj = srcObject.GetType().GetProperties()
        .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == propertyName); //-- Debugger stops here
    return (propInfoSrcObj != null);
}
```

[image]
How can I avoid this code stepping through? My current work around is <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to step out before resuming my debugging with <kbd>F11</kbd>.

Another example of where this is happening is this code.

```
string databaseNamePair = split.Find(f => f.StartsWith("Initial Catalog"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those Linq statements contain lambda expressions that are compiled to method calls. Thus, the attribute is not applied to these distinct methods.

I suppose you could turn the lambdas into full blown methods so that you could tag them with that attribute, but it's going to make for fugly code.

Comment: lol, i have had it. I turned it into `fugly` code! R#8 function `Convert LINQ to Code`.